# Laravel 5.3 Multi Authentication setup

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I would like to use laravel 5.3 authentication for two different tables.
How would it be possible by using laravel authentication?

I have setup auth.php files, and adding guards,
Creating a new model, and migrate the necessary file.

I copied the controllers, and update the namespace, and have specified the route.
And, yes i am able to access that route, to that particular controller..

But, when i register, it goes to users table.
Why and how to set it to the correct table?
I thought guards would do the work.

And also, 
If we use the default laravel authentication , we are not able to set the route?
I mean, i am able to access it, and change it on the route, but when the register post, it goes back to the default route.
I wonder if there's any way to override that..

Thanks a lot

Comment: Plz include the needed code lines to understand the situation well

Comment: _Don’t_ create multiple tables for different user types. It just causes headaches. If you have a table for “users” and a table for say, “admins”; what happens when you introduce a _third_ user type? Are you going to create yet another model, controllers, views, auth guard, etc? Just have “users” and then use authorisation to determine what they can and cannot do in your application.

Comment: There is very nice post related to this topic. Step by step process to create Multi Auth in Laravel. https://www.gautammenariya.com/2018/11/set-up-multiple-authentication-in.html

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by the correct table.You should edit the table name you requied in the register controller
Ex:-

```
$company=  Company::create([
             'companyname' =>($data['companyname']),
             'Address1' =>($data['Address1']),
             'Address2' =>($data['Address2']),
             'telephone' =>($data['telephone']),

        ]);
```

Comment: I have edited the correct table name.

But i think the function is not executed..

cause when i try to return a string, it is not executed.
The default function is executed.

I am thinking like, is there any way, that i can pass in the guard to authentication system, so, that i can reuse the authentication code without copying a set of it

Comment: Did you use the required model in the Register controller? And did you mention the "return"  needed  to your code? ex;- return $users; inside your function

Comment: Yes i did..
I finally finished it up.
Apparently, the mistakes lie in the views file..

I did not override the views file, which is used for default authentication.
After i sorted it out, i finally able to achieve what i want to achieve..

Thanks a lot, Mindi

Answer (score 1):

I am also new but Try to change the table in Register controller

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'user_type'=>$data['user_type'],

    ]);
```

Replace "User" to what you want to enter the data..

As i understood the auth.php...
in there we use the model(table ) to login..

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [

        'driver' => 'eloquent',

        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        'table' => 'users',

    ],
```

try it out...
Sorry if i am wrong..

Comment: Its better if you be more clear on what you want to come up with,,with code segments,,isn't it brother...

Answer (score 1):

> But, when i register, it goes to users table. Why and how to set it to
>   the correct table?

Assuming you are using the auto generated auth controllers, views and routes.
Navigate to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` add `using YourModelName` to the top and change the following function to your own Model.

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

> If we use the default laravel authentication , we are not able to set the route?

If u mean redirection after registration you can also set that in the `RegisterController`

```
 /**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

About the Auth routes. They are automatically set by the following line in your `/routes/web.php`

```
Auth::routes();
```

You can change this by deleting this and replacing it with your desired Auth routes

Comment: Ya, But the function create() is not executed..

Right now, i am defining two sets of similar functions
All is stored in two different folders with different namespace, and i specify the create() function to store different models..

In AdminAuth, i use Admins::create();
in Auth, i use Users::create();

But seems like the function create in AdminAuth is not executed, as it doesn't even return string when i try to return string..

I am thinking if we can specify which guard to be used during registration, to the default authentication system, it would be better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In auth.php this is where is is defined that it will use User model. You can change model from her

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
],
```